# How to simulantenously work on multiple branches while waiting for tests to to run?

Tags: git, testing, tdd

I have a few features that I am working on simultaneously. They are all in a separate branch.

My problem is that when I wait for the tests to run I want to switch to another branch to work on another feature. However, if I checkout another branch to work on another feature then it will interfere with the tests that are currently running. I don't want to push my code until localtests passes.

Has anyone encountered similar issues? What are your solutions so that you don't have to wait for tests to pass?

EDIT: Is there a solution that does not involve cloning a second repo? I have already tried that. Works well, just a little bit annoying!

Comment: Cloning one repo to another, locally, is cheap (on Unix-like systems anyway) as git will make links to the object store, and hence use relatively little disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others note, you can only have one thing checked out in the current directory, more or less by definition.  Local clones are pretty cheap too.  But, if you want to avoid even the clone, you can check out a copy of a branch into some *other* (new) directory and run the tests there, assuming the test framework handles that correctly:

```
mkdir /some/where/else   # or mkdir ../else or whatever
git --work-tree=/some/where/else checkout -- .
```

or (script-able):

```
sh -c 't=$(git rev-parse --git-dir) && export GIT_DIR=$(readlink -f $t) && \
    cd /tmp && mkdir test-xx && cd test-xx && git checkout -- . || \
    echo "unable to check out copy into test dir"'
```

The new / empty directory needs to be empty to make sure no leftover files, that were in some branch but then deleted at some point, are still there.

Answer (score 2):

```
cd .. && git clone repo repo2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one branch checked out at any time.

Two no-so-brilliant ideas come to mind to work around this. First, you could copy all your project files to a testing directory and run your tests there while you continue to work in the repository. Second, although basically the same as the first, is to have the repository cloned in a secondary directory for you to run the tests in while again you continue to work in the original directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). It integrates with git and lets you simply perform tasks on your code.

In you instance, you could create a new test branch and configure Jenkins to run your tests whenever someone pushes to the test branch.